# How do I discard unsaved changes without closing workbook?

Tags: vba

Right now I have this code that runs when the workbook is closed:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wks As Worksheet

Select Case MsgBox("Do you really wish to close this file?", vbQuestion + vbOKCancel, "Close")
Case vbOK:
    Sheets("Start").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not wks.Name = "Start" Then
            wks.Visible = xlVeryHidden
        End If
    Next wks

    ThisWorkbook.Save

Case vbCancel:
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
End Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

My problem is if an user make changes to the workbook, but at the end, doesn't want to save this changes, it ends up saving it anyway. Is there a way for me to revert to previous state before close? Like going to the previous save state, then running the beforeclose code?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a msgbox to ask for user confirmation, and only call `ThisWorkbook.Save` if the user selects yes, like so:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wks As Worksheet

Select Case MsgBox("Do you really wish to close this file?", vbQuestion + vbOKCancel, "Close")
Case vbOK:
    Sheets("Start").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not wks.Name = "Start" Then
            wks.Visible = xlVeryHidden
        End If
    Next wks

    answer = msgbox("Do you want to save?")
    If answer = vbYes Then
       ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If

Case vbCancel:
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
End Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```